# Java about reversing string

Tags: java

I am confused about how to write a program that reverse the phrase but maintain the index chosen. Like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string1 = "He is Chinese";

    System.out.println(reverse(string1));
}

private static String reverse(String string) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int length = string.length();
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        char a = string.charAt(i);
        if(a == ' ') {
            sb.append(a);
        } else {
            int j = i;
            while(j < length && string.charAt(j) != ' ') {
                j++;
            }
            sb.append(ReverseString(string.substring(i, j)));
            i = j-1;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
private static String ReverseString(String string) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=string.length()-1;i>=0; i--) {
        sb.append(string.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

the choosen index is C. i want to keep the C in the places, but the other alphabet is reverse.

the output display is 
 `eH si esenihC`

Comment: Remove the chosen index character. Reverse the string and then re-insert the character at the position.

Comment: What is "the index choosen" in your example?

Comment: its 'C' .. and how to do it .. im quite blank in reversing string ...

Comment: Can you please post sample input and output examples.?

Answer (score 2):

Also if I don't well understand the phrase "maintain the index chosen" I believe that could be  your snippets:

```
public static String reverse( String input ) {
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    String ret = "";
    for( String word : words) {
        if( ret.length() > 0 ) { ret+=" "; }
        ret += new StringBuilder(word).reverse();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Hoping this may help you...Have fun!

Edit: if you want to keep a character in position after words reversing that could be a solution:

```
public static String reverse(String input, String pivot) {
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    String ret = "";
    for( int i = 0; i<words.length; i++ ) {
        if (i != 0) { ret += " "; }
        ret += reverse_word(words[i], pivot);
    }
    return ret;
}

public static String reverse_word(String input, String pivot) {
    // warning: split will lose the last occurrence of pivot
    String[] word_parts = input.split(pivot);
    String ret = "";
    for( int i = 0; i<word_parts.length; i++ ) {
        if (i != 0) { ret += pivot; }
        ret += new StringBuilder(word_parts[i]).reverse();
    }
    // check the last one
    ret += input.endsWith(pivot) ? pivot : "";
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really did not understand that *maintain the index choosen*, but if it is reversing string then,

How about it -

```
private static String reverse(String string) {
    return new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
}
```

---

**Updation** - 
As you said - *and how to keep the 'C' in its own places? like Chinese, the other alphabet is reversing but only "C" is stayed put in its own places*.

```
private static String reverse(String string) {
    if(string==null||string.length()<=1)
         return string;
    return string.subString(0,1)+new StringBuilder(string.subString(1)).reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: and how to keep the 'C' in its own places? like Chinese, the other alphabet is reversing but only "C" is stayed put in its own places.

Comment: This doesn't addresses his question. @Up voter Please read the question carefully and completely.

Comment: A slight modification - `return string.subString(0,1)+new StringBuilder(string.subString(1)).reverse().toString();`

Comment: @Jabir firstly thanks for care to comment, question it self is not clear enough, answer is given a better and shotter whay to achive a solution. Also check the comment trail, where it is clarified and answered.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder - You could edit your answer instead of posting the modified solution in comments. Answers and comments have their own specific purposes!:)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting tangled up here with character indexes, I'd base a solution on the built-in `reverse()` function in the `StringBuilder` class, at the expense of performance.

Assume the preservation index is `n`:

```
char c = string[n];
StringBuilder sb(string).deleteCharAt(n).reverse().insert(n, c);
return sb.toString();
```

Finally, this approach would generalise to an array of such preservation indices - use a loop calling `deleteCharAt()` and a corresponding loop for reinsertion. Do let me know if you need that.

Comment: This doesn't addresses his question